# C# insert query not working

Tags: c#

i have written insert query for my application to create new user with password, but its not working, please check and correct it.

```
 con.Open();
        string a;
        a = "insert into tbl_KKSUser(EName,Uname,Password)values(@en,@un,@pas)";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con);
        SqlParameter paramName;
        paramName = new SqlParameter("@en", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
        paramName.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        cm.Parameters.Add(paramName);

        string original = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
        int h = original.GetHashCode();
        string withHash = original;
        b1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(withHash);
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(b1);
        SqlParameter paramPass;
        paramPass = new SqlParameter("@pas", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
        paramPass.Value = Convert.ToString(encrypted);
        cm.Parameters.Add(paramPass);
        Response.Write("<script>alert('inserted')</alert>");
        con.Close();
```

Comment: "its not working" is never a good enough description of a problem. *Always* say what's actually happening vs what you *expect* to happen.

Comment: Also: you don't set the @un parameter.

Comment: On a side-note: **don't** use `GetHashCode` for persistent hashing. It's not *meant* to be used that way, and you *will* get bitten sooner or later. (For example, IIRC `String.GetHashCode()` in .NET is different on 32-bit processes to 64-bit processes.) - EDIT: It seems that you don't actually use the value of `h` after all. So remove it from your code.

Comment: What about setting the @un parameter?

Comment: (On another side-note, your code would be clearer to read if you assigned variables at the point of declaration, instead of declaring them on one line and then assigning them on the next one.)

Comment: Also you open a <script> tag and then close a </alert>? tag, surely those should match?

Comment: Now I've noticed you're not hashing the password, I see you're using Base64 and calling that "encryption". It's not. Your code is exposing user passwords to anyone who ends up seeing your data.

Comment: Where is your parameter definition for @un? I can't see it - btw @prescott is absolutely right - any error message would be of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call ExecuteNonQuery function before closing connection

```
 con.Open();
            string a;
            a = "insert into tbl_KKSUser(EName,Uname,Password)values(@en,@un,@pas)";
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con);
            SqlParameter paramName;
            paramName = new SqlParameter("@en", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
            paramName.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            cm.Parameters.Add(paramName);

            string original = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
            int h = original.GetHashCode();
            string withHash = original;
            b1 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(withHash);
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(b1);
            SqlParameter paramPass;
            paramPass = new SqlParameter("@pas", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
            paramPass.Value = Convert.ToString(encrypted);
            cm.Parameters.Add(paramPass);

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // here call ExecuteNonQuery

            Response.Write("<script>alert('inserted')</alert>");
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not executing the query. You need to do:

```
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ya.. i was forgot friend, this is what a simple things i forgot to write friend, thats y i made so many like this. bt thanks anyway

Comment: @user1455232, yeah that happens, also follow the suggestions made in comments against your question. That will improve your code a lot

Answer (score 0):

Two things are missing there....

1. You are passing 3 sql variables in the query and adding only two parameters.
2. add the following line too,

   ```
   cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The ExecuteNonQuery() is one of the most frequently used method in SqlCommand Object, and is used for executing statements that do not return result sets (ie. statements like insert data , update data etc.)

so use

```
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And also add all used parameters i.e. 3 parameters in your example.